# How to setup and use a SHA1 hash in Ruby

Tags: ruby, security, sha1

I realize you can create a SHA1 hash in ruby like so:

```
Digest::SHA1.hexdigest "foo"
```

However, once the code is created what are you suppose to do with it? I figure it can be easily hijacked and compromised. Where is the security value in adding this hash? What point am I missing?

Comment: Huh?  If you don't need a hash, then don't create one!

Comment: You miss the usefulness of hashes. Hashes are good for encrypting things `one-way`. The hash algorithm tries to guarantee that: no two documents generate the same algorithm and you cannot reverse the hash to the original data. Would you store passwords for a site in a database with clear text? No. You store the hash of them. And when a user enters his username/password, you hash the password, and look it up in the DB. When somebody hacks your DB, he can steal only the hashes.

Answer (score 3):

You could securely **store passwords**, *without actually storing any passwords.*

```
def password=(new_password)
  @hashed_password = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(new_password + super_secure_salt)
end

def valid_password?(password)
  @hashed_password == Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(password + super_secure_salt)
end

self.password = 'abc123'
self.valid_password?('foobar') #=> false
self.valid_password?('abc123') #=> true
```

You could **recognize a file** by seeing if the hash of the binary contents is identical to something you've seen before:

```
FileRecord.where(sha: Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(some_file.read)).exists?
```

You could **securely obfuscate a url** by requiring a sha1 hash noone knows but a select few to access a resource on a website.

```
# GET /mysecurepages/1234?key=abcd1234abcd1234abcd1234

@resource = Resource.find(params[:id])
if params[:key] == Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(@resource.id + super_secure_salt)
  # allow access
else
  # deny access
end
```

And many many other things. What would you like to do with a SHA1 hash?

---

A final note about this:

> I figure it can be easily hijacked and compromised.

It can only be hijacked and compromised if you dont use a salt (or a not good salt). Salt is like a secret that gets included in the input to the hashing function. And as long as that stays a secret, the input to the SHA1 is very difficult to figure out from the output.

In brief psuedocode a secure hash might looks like:

```
publically_sharable_hash = sha1(commonly_known_input + secret_salt)
```

Where this is only useful for non security applications: (like the file content example above)

```
insecure_hash = sha1(commonly_known_input)
```

Because the math of arriving at a SHA1 hash is well known, it's much easier to know the input from the output when no salt was used.

So if your salt is a long 32-64 character string, it's like have a super secure encryption password on every hash you generate.  But like any password, make sure it stays secret.